# Python 3 functions to locate a set of days within a pandas dataframe and calculate an average of values around these days?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need help with this!

So, I have a list of days that I have prepared in advance, it looks some thing like this:

list_1 = [‘01/01/2022’, ‘04/01/2023’, ‘05/01/2023’]

and I have a separate pandas dataframe that has 2 columns like below:

| Datetime | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 3 |
| 02/01/2023 | 5 |
| 03/01/2023 | 4 |
| 04/01/2023 | 7 |
| 05/01/2023 | 7 |

and so on

I want to make it so that the days in the list will be used to lookup the value in the first column of the dataframe, then calculate the average value over the last 3 days and add this value to a second list.

For example, list_1 contains ‘04/01/2023’ and '05/01/2023' which matches with a day in the first column, so it will take the average of 7, 4, 5 which is 5.33 then 7, 7, 4 which is 6 and add these to a separate list like:

list_2 = [‘5.33’, '6'].

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to perform a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) on 3days, then to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True)

out = (df.set_index('Datetime').rolling('3D').mean()
         .reindex(pd.to_datetime(list_1, dayfirst=True))
       )
```

Output:

```
              Values
2022-01-01       NaN
2023-01-04  5.333333
2023-01-05  6.000000
```

Another one is to use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True)

ref = pd.to_datetime(list_1, dayfirst=True).to_numpy()

dates = df['Datetime'].to_numpy()[:,None]
values = df['Values'].to_numpy()[:,None]

m = (dates <= ref) & (dates > ref-pd.Timedelta('3days'))

out = np.nanmean(np.where(m, np.repeat(values, len(ref), axis=1), np.nan), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([       nan, 5.33333333, 6.        ])
```